# uploading image from react frontend to express backend and displaying it back in the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

All I want to achieve is to upload the image in react frontend, save it in local public/images folder in backend and display the uploaded images back in frontend. So far I have managed to upload the files to backend. I cant figure out how to display the files in frontend. I want to make a get request to send the image files to frontend

express code:
[express code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D53SR.png)

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("./public"));


var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: "./public/images",
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname )
}
})



var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');


app.post('/upload',function(req, res) {
 
upload(req, res, function (err) {
       if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
           return res.status(500).json(err)
       } else if (err) {
           return res.status(500).json(err)
       }
  return res.status(200).send(req.file)

})

});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
console.log("server started at port "+PORT);
});
```

React frontend code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const ImageForm = () => {

const [file, setFile] = useState(null);


const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files);
    console.log(file)
}


const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    for(var x = 0; x<file.length; x++) {
        data.append('file', file[x])
    }
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload", data)
    .then(res => { 
        console.log(res.statusText)
      })
}

return ( 
    <div>
       <form >
        <div className="form-group" >

            <label htmlFor="file">Upload File:</label>
            <input 
            className="form-control-file mb-3" 
            type="file" id="file" 
            accept=".jpg"
            multiple
            onChange={handleFileChange}
            />

            <button 
            className="btn btn-primary mt-3" 
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            >Upload</button>
        </div>
       </form>

       {/* Display Image Here */}
    </div>
 );
}

export default ImageForm;
```

res: [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtrzP.png)

error: [err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIOrt.png)

Comment: You are already sending the file in your response from backend. You just need to handle it from the react app. can you do console.log(res) inside your axios and post the result here?

Comment: i've added it at the end of post @fahimchowdhury

Comment: it seems like the response you are sending from backend is empty. the req.file that you are sending is probably undefined

Comment: But I receive the uploaded images in backend public/images folder @fahimchowdhury

Comment: would you still check whether req.file is logging undefined or not?

Comment: i was sending multiple files at first and i was getting null response so i just tried uploading single file and i'm getting response for that. please check the img i have attached above @fahimchowdhury

Comment: there you go. Now you just need to store the path in a state and set the src value equals to that state inside img tag. Also don't forget to concat the base url with path when you are storing. Try req.files instead of req.file to send multiple files

Comment: If you don't mind could you please send me the code for the same. @fahimchowdhury

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, create a state:

```
const [imgFile, setImgFile] = useState('');
```

Then, replace the following part of your code:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload", data)
.then(res => { 
    setImgFile('http://localhost:5000/public/images/'+res.data.filename)
  })
```

Add this after the form tag

```
<img src={imgFile} alt="img"/>
```

Just in case the image does not load, add this in the express code:

```
app.use('/public/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images/'));
```

Comment: I'm getting error on submit. image attached above @fahimchowdhury

Comment: does the image load if you paste the url in your browser?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's done. Actually I had assigned public folder as static folder so I just had to modify path in react to localhost/images/.

Comment: ^ yes that saved me, thanks Sharven. Worth noting, if the path is "localhost/images/" that actually refers to the images in the folder "public/images"