# How to upload some images from back express/node and render in front with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, react-fullstack

I'm working on a full-stack project using React, Express, and Node.

I have created a JSON file on the backend with some information such as name, description, and pictures. Here's an example:

`id: 1`
`name: Earth`
`description: The Earth is a planet`
`image: images/earth.jpg`

My picture is located in a public folder (inside back called "server" folder) like this:

`server/data/public/images/earth.jpg`

What code do I need to write on the backend to upload pictures and display them on the frontend? I have already retrieved other information from the backend and displayed it on the frontend (`name`, `description`), but the picture isn't working.

I wrote the code `app.use(express.static('public');` and tried that :

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = `${__dirname}/data/public/images/planetes.json`;
  const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, ));
  res.json(data);
});
```

But is not working.

Any suggestions ? Thank you !

Comment: I'm a bit confused why would you wanna send a `.json` file extension if you actually need to send an image file ? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176583/12737879) is what you're looking for `express.static` middleware?

Comment: Because each id have their own image, so when i will map it, each image will come with their informations.

Thanks, I will check the topic

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `sendFile` [API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile) that Express provides?